# Community Wiki questions

Tags: support, community-wiki

For example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature

is an open question.  Yes it was eventually closed, but my question is - what for and when should we make questions into community wikis, rather than closing? I have some ideas for questions along these lines, but want some official guidance on stackexchange policies for this.  Support? :)

Comment: It's difficult. There are a lot of similar questions as you linked above that were not only closed but deleted. (You can see them nevertheless if your +10k user)

Comment: see here for a good overview: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73455/147248

Comment: Man, there are some awesome questions in there.  However none of the links work...even for me with > 10k...

Comment: not all of them work, but there are some cool ones that work

Comment: Mark you have to be a 10k user on the site the question is located. Most of them are on SO and there you're not a 10k user

Comment: Ah, blast... :) Well that's just annoying.

Comment: Another reason to increase the SO rep ;)

Comment: Sadly, Mark Mayo is not the Jon Skeet of StackOverflow (-;

Comment: Why not? I think he is!

Comment: ah now i understand :D should read more carefully.

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a [blog article](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) that discusses Community Wiki.

**You should never make a question Community Wiki just as a means to avoid closure**. Community Wikis purpose is enhanced editing, not an enabler. If you want to avoid closing a question, fix what problems it has. The ideal question to keep is one where you don't have to even think about considering Community Wiki.

If it's valuable enough to stay, it should be a part of the site like a normal question. If it isn't valuable enough to stay, it shouldn't be on the site. There are times where it may work to have a community wiki question - these are few and far between, and are exceptional circumstances. And, moreover, what makes them acceptable *won't* be the Community Wiki status.

Essentially, if you're thinking about whether a question belongs, don't put Community Wiki in the equation. Community Wiki matters for collaboration - it should be used expressly for that purpose. And honestly, that happens generally only in answers, not in questions.